# How to Change the webpart being displayed on home page based on time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I have a requirement where I have to display on the home page a particular web part between 7 a.m and 9 A.M and another web part the rest of the time. Can anyone suggest me an approach to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? People are here to help if you run into a specific problem, but they're not here to do the whole thing for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))